# TypeORM Class constructor Guild cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm building a bot for discord using discordjs, TypeORM and Typescript, I running bot using typescript is great but... I compile the code and run with js, not work :/

That error happen when I select a field in database...

*Error in Console*

```
(node:11452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Class constructor Guild cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at SelectQueryBuilder.QueryBuilder.createFromAlias (D:\nevr001\ava-discord\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\QueryBuilder.js:396:35)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.from (D:\nevr001\ava-discord\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\SelectQueryBuilder.js:131:30)
    at Object.getPrefix (D:\nevr001\ava-discord\dist\controllers\Guild.controller.js:62:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (D:\nevr001\ava-discord\dist\index.js:56:38)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11452) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

*This line invoke the function with error*

```
const { prefix, prefixLength } = await GuildController().getPrefix(Number(message.guild?.id) || 0)
```

**This is function to getPrefix in database**

```
// Get prefix of the guild on DATABASE
    async function getPrefix(id: number): Promise<ResponseGetPrefix> {
        if (await !existGuild(id)) return {}

        const response = await getConnection('sqlite')
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .select(["guild.prefix", "guild.prefixLength"])
            .from(Guild, "guild")
            .where("guild.id = :id", { id })
            .getOneOrFail()

        return { prefix: response.prefix, prefixLength: response.prefixLength }
    }
```

*This is my model*

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm'

@Entity()
export default class Guild {
    @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'numeric', unique: true })
    id: number

    @Column('varchar')
    name: string

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', default: '$' })
    prefix: string

    @Column({ type: 'integer', default: 1 })
    prefixLength: number

    @Column({ type: 'simple-array', array: true, default: '' })
    channels_command: string[]

    @Column({ type: 'simple-array', array: true, default: '' })
    channels_chat: string[]

    @Column({ type: 'boolean', default: true })
    welcome_message_status: boolean

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', default: '' })
    channel_welcome: string

    @Column({ type: 'simple-array', array: true, default: '' })
    prefix_redirect: string[]

    @Column('numeric')
    memberCount: number

    @Column('varchar')
    region: string

    @Column('varchar')
    ownerID: string

    @Column('boolean')
    deleted: boolean

    @Column('varchar')
    joined: number
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code and errors [directly in your question instead of images]? It will be easier to help you that way.

Comment: I don't have reputation

Comment: You do have the reputation to the raw text of your code and errors directly into your question, though. See [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I edited the question, now it's all sure?